# No response when adding second onclick listener

Tags: java, android, button, textview, onclicklistener

I am currently working on a login screen for an android project.  It has a button for the login and a textview that is to work as a button if the user does not have an account.  The Login screen was working beautifully but once I added an onClick listener to the text view neither of them are responding.  I am at a loss for what is going wrong because if I comment out the textview it works fine.

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Declare Global Variables
private EditText emailText;
private EditText passwordText;
private TextView signUpText;
private Button loginButton;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListen;
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_login);
    initVar();
    initFireBase();
    initOnClick();
}

private void initVar() {
    emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
    passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    signUpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUpText);
    Log.d(TAG, "Setting Variables to Relative ID's");
}

private void initFireBase() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListen = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeScreen.class));
                Log.d(TAG, "Loading Home Screen");
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
}

private void initOnClick() {
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
            Log.d(TAG, "Executing Sign On");
        }
    });

    signUpText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading SignUp Screen");
        }
    });
}

private void signIn() {

    String email = emailText.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordText.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Put In Password or Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to Sign In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListen);
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListen != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListen);
    }
}

}
```

Login Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="55dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="197dp"
            android:layout_height="223dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_final" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:id="@+id/emailText"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="passwordText"
            android:id="@+id/password"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Login"
        tools:textColor="#ffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.044"
        tools:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:ignore="OnClick" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/signUpText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Don't have an account?" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: I figured it out, i was calling an unresponsive layout for the second activity that looked the same

Comment: just to make sure, where you comment out textview? In xml or you are just commenting out it's onclicklistener?

Comment: I comment it out it's onclicklistener

Comment: Instead of declaring onclicklisteners in seperate method just define them in oncreate() method. I know it sounds weird but just give it a try. If it doesn't work then try by implementing OnClickListener interface in line of your class definition and just implement single onclicklistener and in it check for id's to determine which view is clicked and perform action according to it.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani I will try that thank you.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani I resoled the problem, I was calling the same layout in the new activity(It was very late). So it looked identical but it was not responsive.

Comment: okay. Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code, I was calling an inactive layout that was the same as the login screen...doh